# How to run linux process and come back to it later?

Tags: linux, shell, process, gnu-screen

I'm trying to run a minecraft server on linux. Running the server starts an important interactive session. I can run the server in the background by appending `&` at the end of the command and log off the server. But then I don't know how to get back to that interactive session when I log back in.

I know about `screen`, but it seems like there should be a better way of running processes in the background and being able to go into them later.

Comment: @SvenW if you make that comment into a answer I'll credit you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen` (or `tmux`) *is* the best option for this and written for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Or `dtach`. (See questions tagged with [tag:dtach]).

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper way to do it:

- Start the process without the `&`
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the process
- Execute on that command line the process `bg`. This will take your process to the background as if you had it executed using the `&`.
- At any point in time you can bring your process to the foreground by using `fg`
- Also, you can get a list of currently executing processes by executing `jobs`

Comment: Sounds perfect, can I log out of the ssh session while a process is bg'ed and then log back in and fg into it?

Comment: no, you can't. To achieve that, as already stated by SvenW, you should use screen or tmux.